# jQuery Not Working in Mobile Version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

The jQuery gallery works fine in the desktop version. Notice how if you click on an image, it opens with a lightbox. However, when viewed on a mobile browser, there is no lightbox. What's causing the jQuery to fail in the mobile version only?

http://globalefficientenergy.com/latest-news/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be because the jQuery `<script>` tags are included at the bottom of the `<body>` of your page instead of inside the `<head>`. I tried to click on a picture on desktop _before_ the page finished loading and the lightbox didn’t open. When I _waited_ for the page to load it did open a lightbox.

Comment: You need to be more specific, which mobile browsers are you refering to and what device(s) are you using? i just had a look on google chrome using a tablet and i don't see a problem. You need to wait for the page to load.